# UWP (C#) - Where and how should files be saved and accessed?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

Where and how should files be saved and accessed, e.g. Images downloaded by my application and then visible from my app.

Scenario:

I give my app URLs to images placed online on random places. The app downloads them and saves them "somewhere". Saved images are used as news article images in my app. Files should be accessible in the Photos app.

Answer (score 2):

Save your data to `ApplicationData.LocalFolder`, it is intended for exactly this. But your data will not be visible outside your app. If you want to make some photos accessible in the Photos app, you need to save them to the `Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary` folder.